# Find the highest value of each type after summing like values MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
Name | Type | aID | bID | cnt
s1   | ta   | 1   | 10  | 5
s2   | tb   | 1   | 11  | 10
s3   | ta   | 1   | 12  | 11
s1   | ta   | 1   | 23  | 2
s2   | tb   | 1   | 54  | 4
s3   | ta   | 2   | 23  | 7
s4   | tc   | 1   | 93  | 5
s4   | tc   | 2   | 82  | 2
```

Given an `aID`, I want to return the top element of each type after summing values with the same `Name` and `aID` together.

For example, given an `aID` of one, the result should be:

`s3` of type `ta` with `cnt` of 11.

`s2` of type `tb` with `cnt` of 14.

`s4` of type `tc` with `cnt` of 5.

There are a large number of aIDs and ~10 or so types. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible of course. Haven't you tried it yet? Have youbeen able to get the sum per Name and aID, yet? What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I have been able to get the sum per name and aID, but that's about as far as I got.

Comment: You should include that query in your request and mention exactly that. Thus people will know where you are stuck and may be able to build up on your query. Ranking has become easy as of MySQL 8 with `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK` analytic functions (or `ROW_NUMBER` when you are ready to pick one name arbitrarily in case of ties).

Comment: SELECT Name,Type, SUM(cnt) as cnt FROM `test` WHERE aID = 1 GROUP BY Name

Comment: @sartajahmed: Your query is invalid. You must not select `Type` when the group can contain multiple types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic functions for a MySQL 8+ option:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, Type, aID, SUM(cnt) AS cnt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, aID
                              ORDER BY SUM(cnt) DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Name, Type, aID
)

SELECT Name, Type, aID, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY aID, Name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

This query works by first aggregating by `Name`, `Type`, *and* `aID`, generating sums of counts for each group.  We then use `ROW_NUMBER` with a partition only on the `Name` and `aID`, to find the row having the `Type` with the maximum count.  Keep in mind that analytic functions are applied *after* the `GROUP BY` has happened, so `ROW_NUMBER` here operates on the aggregate rows, not the rows of your original table.

Comment: Thank you! However, I wish to only return the results for one specific aID, and not all aID in general. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Bill Wang: Yes, by applying a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple query?:

```
SELECT 
    Type, MAX(t.total) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        Name, Type, SUM(cnt) total 
     FROM 
        tablename 
     WHERE 
        aID = 1 
     GROUP BY 
        Name, Type ) t 
GROUP BY 
    Type;
```

Comment: This query doesn't return the names.